# How to get the names of output nodes in TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write inference system for TensorFlow models. User will can choose completed model in format .pb and run my inference system, so he will can see results. For example, if it is detection model, he would see image with detection boxes, or classification - he would see list with predictions and classes (labels).

There are a lot of TensorFlow models and there are a lot of its architecture.
And my question: How can I get the names of output nodes in TensorFlow model in format `.pb` if I don't know which model user will run?
I dont want to add parameter `--name_output` in my parser... Is there another way?
For example, I can find out the names of input nodes using it:

```
nodes = [n.name + ' => ' +  n.op for n in graph_def.node if n.op in ('Placeholder')]
```

But how can I get the names of output nodes?

I use TensorFlow and python.

Comment: There is no way to do this reliably, really, unless you have specific constraints in your model that guarantee that your method works. You could, for example, look for nodes in which the output is not connected to the input of any other node, but it is very likely that you have other intermediate operations that match that condition (unless the models used something like [`convert_variables_to_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants), which removes unused nodes).

Comment: The "good" way of doing this is saving the models in the [SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model), which includes the graph itself but also metadata like the "function signatures" in the graph the indicate the input and output nodes.

Comment: Tensorboard can show the op-level graph which includes all the computation nodes involved. For more see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#op-level_graph). Thanks!